# Заполнить DataGrid через Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Недавно начал изучать wpf поэтому могу задавать достаточно глупые вопросы. Итак есть `DataGrid`

```
       <Page.DataContext>
           <local:ClientPortfellVM />
       </Page.DataContext>
  //....
       <DataGrid Margin="0,50,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"  IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Balance" IsReadOnly="True"  MaxWidth="200" MinWidth="200" Binding="{Binding Balance}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

который нужно заполнить строками. Вью моделью является вот такой класс :

```
 public class ClientPortfellVM
 {

    public ObservableCollection<FundViewModel> collection = new ObservableCollection<FundViewModel>();    


    public class FundViewModel
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Balance { get; set; }
    } 

}
```

И теперь мне нужно, как я понимаю заполнить коллекцию примерно так :

```
    collection.Add(new FundViewModel() { Type = "111", Balance = "222" });
```

Только куда её вписывать, если все написанное вообще правильно, не знаю - подскажите кто знает, а если неправильно поправьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых сделайте collection свойством, иначе привязка не пройдет:

```
public ObservableCollection<FundViewModel> Collection { get; set }
```

Свойства принято писать с заглавной буквы.

заполняете коллекцию в методе или напрямую из конструктора класса:

```
public class ClientPortfellVM
{

    public ObservableCollection<FundViewModel> Сollection { get; set; }

    public ClientPortfellVM()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<FundViewModel>(); 
        Collection.Add(new FundViewModel() { Type = "111", Balance = "222" });
    }


    public class FundViewModel
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Balance { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

---

> но у меня всего 2 столбца должно быть, а появляется целых 4

все дело в свойстве **AutoGenerateColumns**. По умолчанию оно установлено в **true**, что говорит что таблица автоматически генерирует столбцы в зависимости от того сколько свойств в классе. Установите его в false и все будет как надо:

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,50,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"  IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Balance" IsReadOnly="True"  MaxWidth="200" MinWidth="200" Binding="{Binding Balance}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но у меня всего 2 столбца должно быть, а появляется целых 4. 2 лишних.

Comment: строка имеет вид -`111`-`222`-`111`-`222`

Comment: @Сергей, с помощью `DataGridTextColumn` вы описали в разметке только 2 столбца. Опишите еще 2 и настройте в них привязку нужным образом.

Comment: @Vlad вы меня не поняли у меня ДОЛЖНО быть 2 столбца(я же описал 2) но появляется 4

Comment: @Сергей, обновил ответ

Comment: @Сергей, да, неправильно понял. Gardes уже ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо теперь все работает как и нужно!

Comment: @Сергей, пожалуйста, обращайтесь.